# best practice to get derived class instances

Tags: java

I've got a class called AbstractPlayer which contains basic variables and methods to play audio. Users are allowed to add audio streams and if a user starts a stream, a derived player should be started by parsing the audio type.
Currently i use a FileExtensionParser:

```
public class FileExtensionParser {
public  FileExtension parseFileExtension(String filename) {
    if (filename.endsWith(".mp3")) {
        return FileExtension.MP3;
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".m3u")) {
        return FileExtension.M3U;
    }
    return FileExtension.UNSUPPORTED_TYPE;
}
```

Then i iniitialize an specialised player by the return type of the parsed file extenion. Is there a better way to return a fitting player? Maybe integrated in a factory pattern?

Comment: This problem perfectly fit factory method design pattern. Instead of `FileExtensions`, you might return concrete media player with configured file extensions

Comment: That's what i thought :) I need the file extensions to fit the player type but I will return a pre-configured player with set URL where you just need to press play. Thanks :)